# Filtering array

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I have an array of people objects (20 in all) from a json file

```
{
      "id": "1",
      "departments": "1",
      "name": "Jim Smith",

},
```

I want to filter ids 1, 5, and 10

```
let values = [1,5,10];

let filtered =this.people.filter(function(person) {
    return values.some(function(val) { return person.id === val });
})


console.log(filtered);
```

I keep getting a blank value in filtered, where am I going wrong? It looks close.

Comment: `"1" == 1` but `"1" !== 1`

Answer (score 2):

Loose typing rules:

```
"1" == 1
"1" !== 1
```

Changing your `===` to a `==` is one way to fix it.

Comment: This was doing my head in, of course I just changed the json to a integer (no quotes). It was so obvious.

Comment: Everybody who has ever written one line of JS has encountered this problem, most more than once, and quite a few (like yourself, and myself) have spent hours scratching their head over it. You'll encounter it again, but you'll probably get to the fix in less time. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the value is integer, while the persion.id is String.

you can use

```
return person.id === val.toString()
```

or

```
return person.id == val
```

And I prefer:

```
let filtered2 = this.people.filter(function(person) {
  return person.id in values;
})
console.log(filtered2);
```